# RPMbuild with executable files

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying to build a RPM (rpmbuild -bb spec file). 
When installing rpm some of executable tcl files are corrupted and all files having same size.

Comment: Please put more information in your question.

Comment: I am sourcing tcl executable and some other text files files in RPM. After building and installing RPM all the tcl files having same size and corrupted. Text files are not affected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declaring '%global __os_install_post %{nil}' in spec file would solve the issue. 
When RPM building it strip files. If tcl executables files stripped it will corrupt the file.

Comment: You might want to file a bug with Red Hat if that is the case. The strip scripts have custom logic for various types of files (e.g. `jar`), and if there's something special about `tcl` that they are somehow corrupted, it should be reported.

Comment: Thanks @AaronD.Marasco